What is the "Fee" on solscan.io transaction page?
What is fee here in the following picture?  Is it the base fee?
This is from a transaction page on solscan.io.
https://solscan.io/tx/23RB1VwHiJcUwo9Z6uRweKy8yJdk2KNXPY8Q1enjC7fTwU5UaS6e7bSaoUHrNdf59ZDB5944kwqqUxwe5RgKgvcJ
I think base fee should be a static 0.000005 SOL? Why is it 0.000009 SOL here?
I used Jupiter API to compose this txn. In this txn I used Jupiter's priority fee setting:
prioritizationFeeLamports :{ "priorityLevelWithMaxLamports": { "priorityLevel": "veryHigh", "maxLamports": 5000000 } }



I think of it as the sum of base and priority.
If the transaction has two signers, then the base fee is 0.00001 sol.
However, if there is only one signer, the base fee is always 0.000005 sol.
Please consider this transaction.
https://solscan.io/tx/3ojBRKHU9PjMy5TE7LK46q2DZtqJwDyKutAoLw3V557TBJGVucpbLckMsN8WQJd4A7sBWwz8EyjW5nQXd8CAKdTD
Thank you.
